# Как закинуть библиотеку font-awesome при помощи gulp в нужную папку для дальнейшего подключения в проект

Tags: gulp

Сама библиотека установлена в проект: `npm i font-awesome --save-dev`

gulpfile.js

```
var awesome = require('font-awesome');

gulp.task('font-aw', function(){
return gulp.src('./node_modules/font-awesome/**.*')
.pipe(gulp.dest('./app/libs/font-awesome/'));
});
```

При запуске в консоли таска gulp font-aw,
пишет не найден модуль font-awesome

Comment: эту сроку уберите `var awesome = require('font-awesome');`

Comment: спасибо, разобрался

Answer (score 1):

```
bower i font-awesome
```

А подключение в gulp делаете так в libs:

```
@import "../libs/font-awesome/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome-all.css"
```